# Is there a correct folder/file structure for request specs on rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, request, integration-testing, rspec-rails

Using RSpec (If it makes a difference)

I'm used to writing Controller specs, and knowing where to place each test was easy, as I just had a file per controller inside `spec/controllers`. I'm now starting to use Request specs, and though at first I thought using the same file structure, I now read that request specs could contain different calls to different routes (pointing to different controllers) inside the *same* test, and now I'm at a loss and couldn't find what would be a correct file structure for the tests.

Say I have a test that creates a resource A (post /resource_A), then creates a resource B (post resource_B) and then checks that on GET /resource_A/previously_created_a_id I get the created resource B as an associated resource, and all this endpoints go to different controllers, on what file should I put this test?

I can of course just make up the folder structure as I see fit, but I like convention over configuration, and I couldn't find this answered anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

`spec/requests` is the default. [From the docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec)...

> Request specs are marked by `:type => :request` or if you have set `config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` by placing them in `spec/requests`.

There is no clear guidance beyond that. But organizing them by route seems to make sense.

> *Say I have a test that creates a resource A (post /resource_A), then creates a resource B (post resource_B) and then checks that on GET /resource_A/previously_created_a_id I get the created resource B as an associated resource, and all this endpoints go to different controllers, on what file should I put this test?*

This is a test that `/resource_A/:id` displays its associated resource. Creating the associated resource_B is test setup and, unless there's a good reason, should not happen via a route. That would be tested as part of resource_B.

Here I'm assuming you're using [FactoryBot](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md). If you're not, you still wouldn't make test resources by calling a route, but instead by using the model or controller.

```
# spec/requests/resource_a_spec.rb
Rspec.describe 'ResourceA management' do
  let(:resource_A) { create(:resource_a) }

  describe '/resource_A/:id' do
    context 'with a b' do
      let(:resource_B) { create(:resource_b) }

      before {
        resource_A.update!(b: resource_b)
      }

      it 'sees its associated resource' do
        get "/resource_A/#{resource_A.id}"
        ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

As your tests for a route grow larger, you might want to split them up into separate files. Depends on what you're testing. For example, you could do it by action.

```
spec/
  requests/
    resource_a/
      show_spec.rb    # GET /resource_A/:id
      index_spec.rb   # GET /resource_A/
      create_spec.rb  # GET /resource_A/new and POST /resource_A
      edit_spec.rb    # GET /resource_A/:id/edit and PATCH /resource_A/:id
      destroy_spec.rb # DELETE /resource_A/:id
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I treated this kind of specs as you say, creating data beforehand with FactoryBot, the thing that got me confused is in that very link that you shared, where they have examples and so I understand they recommend using and testing things for multiple requests in the same spec

Comment: @DJA Those are examples to demonstrate request spec functionality and each controls the whole file; I wouldn't take them as recommendations on larger spec structure. Start with one file per resource, and then if it gets too large split it up along whatever lines make sense.